# can I control two sony DSC-QX30 cameras at same time for 3D image shooting?

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I like to develop a android APP to remote control two sony DSC-QX30 cameras. By doing so , I can create 3D image and video. I know Gopro has a bridge to connect two cameras , can Sony provide the same support ?

Comment: Your question has little to do with programming and does not, as such, belong on stackoverflow. I suggest contacting Sony or using one of their related forums.

Comment: Curiously Sony directs these questions to SO: https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras and https://developer.sony.com/support/how-to-post-tag-a-question/ and the OP's question is about API

Comment: that's right,, Sony direct us to the SO to ask question.. However, I did not see Sony's rep answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out libgphoto2. This is a list of supported cameras: http://gphoto.sourceforge.net/proj/libgphoto2/support.php, and I don't see your specific model here. However if it supports any of the standard picture transfer protocols (MTP, PTP or PictBridge), it should be possible to use it.